# Error: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: React is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, preact

I have been getting this error for a while now.
**Entire picture:**
I have made a react component into a npm module and am trying to use that npm module in another project which uses `preact` instead of `react`. The above error occurs as soon as the page on the project tries to load.

I bundled my npm module using webpack, here is my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
entry: "./src/components/index.js",
output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    libraryTarget: 'umd',      
    publicPath: '/dist/',      
    umdNamedDefine: true 
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
              }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                publicPath: './src/fonts/',
                name: './src/fonts/[name].[ext]',
                limit: 1000
            }
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    alias: {
        "react" : "preact-compat",
    "react-dom" : "preact-compat"
    }
    
},
externals: {      
    // Don't bundle react or react-dom      
    react: {          
        commonjs: "react",          
        commonjs2: "react",          
        amd: "React",          
        root: "React"      
    },      
    "react-dom": {          
        commonjs: "react-dom",          
        commonjs2: "react-dom",          
        amd: "ReactDOM",          
        root: "ReactDOM"      
     }  
 }
}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
   "name": "tutorial12",
    "version": "1.0.41",
    "description": "",
    "main": "./dist/main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "buildWebpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
       "preload-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0-beta.3",
       "webpack": "4.43.0",
       "webpack-cli": "3.3.12",
       "babel-plugin-react-transform": "3.0.0",
       "css-loader": "3.6.0",
       "file-loader": "6.0.0",
       "style-loader": "1.2.1",
       "url-loader": "4.1.0",
       "react": "16.8.3",
       "react-redux": "5.0.7",
       "redux": "4.0.0",
       "redux-thunk": "2.3.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
       "@babel/cli": "7.10.4",
       "@babel/core": "7.10.4",
       "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.10.4",
       "@babel/preset-env": "7.10.4",
       "@babel/preset-react": "7.10.4",
        "babel-loader": "8.1.0"
     }
   }
```

The things I have tried:

1. Adding a `resolve: {alias: {"react": "preact-compat", "react-dom" : "preact-compat"}}` in webpack.config.js
2. Adding a `resolve: {alias: {"react": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react"), "react-dom" : path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react-dom")}}` in webpack.config.js.
3. Adding a `resolve: {alias: {"react": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/preact-compat"), "react-dom" : path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react-dom")}}`
4. Moving the dependencies in the package.json from `devDependencies` field to `dependencies` field

Here's the stacktrace of the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: React is not defined
at i.value (main.js:1)
at callMethod (preact-compat.es.js:491)
at i.render (preact-compat.es.js:502)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:728)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at buildComponentFromVNode (preact.esm.js:856)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:397)
at innerDiffNode (preact.esm.js:516)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:439)
at innerDiffNode (preact.esm.js:516)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:439)
at innerDiffNode (preact.esm.js:516)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:439)
at innerDiffNode (preact.esm.js:516)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:439)
at diff (preact.esm.js:348)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:769)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:746)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:746)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at buildComponentFromVNode (preact.esm.js:842)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:397)
at innerDiffNode (preact.esm.js:516)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:439)
at innerDiffNode (preact.esm.js:516)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:439)
at diff (preact.esm.js:348)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:769)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at buildComponentFromVNode (preact.esm.js:842)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:397)
at innerDiffNode (preact.esm.js:516)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:439)
at innerDiffNode (preact.esm.js:516)
at idiff (preact.esm.js:439)
at diff (preact.esm.js:348)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:769)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:746)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:746)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:746)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:746)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
at renderComponent (preact.esm.js:746)
at setComponentProps (preact.esm.js:676)
value   @   main.js:1
callMethod  @   preact-compat.es.js:491
(anonymous) @   preact-compat.es.js:502 
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:728
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
buildComponentFromVNode @   preact.esm.js:856
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:397
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
diff    @   preact.esm.js:348
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:769
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
buildComponentFromVNode @   preact.esm.js:842
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:397
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
diff    @   preact.esm.js:348
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:769
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
buildComponentFromVNode @   preact.esm.js:842
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:397
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
diff    @   preact.esm.js:348
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:769
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
buildComponentFromVNode @   preact.esm.js:842
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:397
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
innerDiffNode   @   preact.esm.js:516
idiff   @   preact.esm.js:439
diff    @   preact.esm.js:348
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:769
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
rerender    @   preact.esm.js:163
Promise.then (async)        
enqueueRender   @   preact.esm.js:154
setState    @   preact.esm.js:951
onStateChange   @   connectAdvanced.js:205
dispatch    @   redux.js:221
e   @   VM9188:1
(anonymous) @   index.js:28
(anonymous) @   index.js:11
dispatch    @   redux.js:563
(anonymous) @   index.js:110
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   index.js:94
(anonymous) @   index.js:11
(anonymous) @   redux.js:449
componentDidMount   @   index.js:112
flushMounts @   preact.esm.js:328
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:821
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
setComponentProps   @   preact.esm.js:676
renderComponent @   preact.esm.js:746
rerender    @   preact.esm.js:163
Promise.then (async)        
enqueueRender   @   preact.esm.js:154
setState    @   preact.esm.js:951
onStateChange   @   connectAdvanced.js:205
dispatch    @   redux.js:221
e   @   VM9188:1
(anonymous) @   index.js:28
(anonymous) @   index.js:11
dispatch    @   redux.js:563
(anonymous) @   index.js:110
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   index.js:94
(anonymous) @   index.js:11
(anonymous) @   redux.js:449
componentDidMount   @   index.js:82
flushMounts @   preact.esm.js:328
diff    @   preact.esm.js:357
render  @   preact.esm.js:991
render$1    @   preact-compat.es.js:149
./src/index.js  @   index.js:10
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap 183f69c…:678
fn  @   bootstrap 183f69c…:88
0   @   socketManager.js:101
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap 183f69c…:678
(anonymous) @   bootstrap 183f69c…:724
(anonymous) @   bootstrap 183f69c…:724
```

Comment: It would be useful if you provide the stacktrace of that error.

Comment: @Herz3h, added the stacktrace from the console of inspect element

Comment: what bundler(requirejs, webpack, etc..) are you using in preact based web project?

Comment: @RazRonen , the other preact based project is mainly made up of require calls and no bundler, think of it like another project created out of create-react-app like script, except that instead of wherever react could have been used, it has been replaced with preact

Comment: got you. Do you want your npm package(webpack project) to do the react packing for you or do you want the package user to handle the packing and dependency of it?

Comment: @RazRonen I want the npm package to have the react packing, the package user should not feel the need to download it seperately, ideally